# Safely parsing user defined equations in Python 3 without eval

Tags: python, security

I have a number of variables in my code such as STA, INT, AGI and dmg_taken, and want the dmg_taken to be calculated by a user defined equation. As a proof of concept I used eval, and this works as follows.

**unsafe.py**

```
dmg_min   = eval(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_min'])
dmg_max   = eval(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_max'])
```

The external rules file that has the equation looks like

**battle.rules**

```
dmg_min = 2
dmg_max = round(((STR * 1.5) + (AGI * 1.02) + (INT * 1.3)) / 6 )
```

The rules can be numbers or formulas containing any number of the variables used in the program - what is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come across a completely safe way to do this so worked out the following.

1. User defined equations can be done by users of the library in python code (basically they can do what they want as they control the code)
2. For external users, all equation parameters are split into variables and read in as numbers so no evaluation is required.

**Modifications to rules file**

```
dmg_INT_mult = 0.9
dmg_AGI_mult = 1.2
dmg_STR_mult = 1.2
dmg_INT_add = -.5
dmg_AGI_add = 0
dmg_STR_add = 0
dmg_overall_mult = 0.1667
dmg_overall_add = 0
```

These parameters are used to build up the equation in the battle.py program

```
#   dmg_max = round(
#                    ((STR + dmg_STR_add) * dmg_STR_mult) 
#                  + ((AGI + dmg_AGI_add) * dmg_AGI_mult) 
#                  + ((INT + dmg_INT_add) * dmg_INT_mult)
#                  ) * dmg_overall_mult 
#             + dmg_overall_add
```

**New Code**

```
calc_agi = round((AGI + float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_AGI_add'])) * float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_AGI_mult']))
calc_int = round((INT + float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_INT_add'])) * float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_INT_mult']))
calc_str = round((STR + float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_STR_add'])) * float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_STR_mult'])) 
dmg_max = round((calc_agi + calc_int + calc_str) * float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_overall_mult']) + float(self.rules.all_rules['dmg_overall_add']))
```

This is safe in that all parameters read in are cast to floats so any strings will cause an exception, and allows for reasonably complex equations to be built up by end users.

Comment: Link to code is https://github.com/acutesoftware/virtual-AI-simulator/blob/master/vais/battle.py#L226